# Creating Excel file in C# gives and error in Office 2003

Tags: c#, office-2007, office-2003

I am creating an application that creates an Excel file when a button clicked without saving it, it works fine in my local machine while there is Microsoft Office 2007.
The problem that when I put this application on server which has Microsoft Office 2003 it gives me an error about something like this `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=12.0.0.0`

Is it because I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` API ? I've searched about this problem and found some solutions that didn't work as expected like downloading `PIA` !!

Comment: please put the complete error which you are getting.

Comment: @Yogendra It gives me the following error: 
`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'`

Comment: do you add reference for that in your application

Comment: Yes of course I've added this reference  `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`

Comment: In your server you have to install the latest version of `office`, as it is `2003` you are getting that error

Comment: You can find `PIA` here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa159923(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Office 2007 on your server. Since you cannot redistribute microsoft dlls with your application, the machines should in that case have required Dlls in the GAC.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this when the administrator of the server gives me the permission.